# Django Blog Posts Ordered From Newest to Oldest

Tags: python, django

I am setting up a blog website and when I add blog posts, the oldest is on the top of the list. How do I reverse this so that the newest posts are on top of the page?

This is my pages/models.py I don't know if ordered_posts = Post.objects.order_by('created_date') is in the right place. I'm not sure where to put it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
 class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    body = models.TextField()

    ordered_posts = Post.objects.order_by('-created_date')

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Remove the `-` from `Post.objects.order_by('-created_date')` and it should sort in the right order. You probably want that piece of code in the view that displays the posts.

Comment: It depends.  Is each `Post` object a different blog post?  What property are you trying to access with `Post.objects`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `ordering` in your class Meta.

> This is a tuple or list of strings and/or query expressions. Each string is a field name with an optional “-” prefix, which indicates descending order. Fields without a leading “-” will be ordered ascending.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    body = models.TextField()

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_date']
```

[See docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#ordering)

Comment: I actually end up using the "-" and it worked for me instead. Thank you for the help. That's all I needed.